# Running doctests using a different function

Tags: python-3.x, doctest

I wrote a module with a few functions along with their doctests, and I would like to run these tests on functions with the same names but written by someone else.

The documentation provides the following snippet for retrieving all tests for `somefunction` in `mymodule` and then running them in the usual way (like running `doctest.testmod()`):

```
TESTS = doctest.DocTestFinder().find(mymodule.somefunction)
DTR = doctest.DocTestRunner(verbose=True)
for test in TESTS:
    print (test.name, '->', DTR.run(test))
```

But I don't know where to go from here to have those tests run on `theirmodule.somefunction` instead. I tried changing the `filename` field from `mymodule` to `theirmodule` in the `Example` objects for each test, but to no avail. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but simply copying my docstrings to their functions in my script works:

```
theirmodule.somefunction.__doc__ = mymodule.somefunction.__doc__
```

And then I only need to run the snippet in my question on `theirmodule.somefunction`.